# Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance - Bot 4.0 WebChat.js

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-edge, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

> [object Error]: {message: "Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable
>   instance", stack: "TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure
>   non-iterable instance at e.exports
>   (https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js:1:566613)
>   at e.exports  at t.unstable_runWithPriority
>   (https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js:1:351563)
>   at Rs
>   (https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js:1:339772)
>   at Ps
>   (https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js:1:339567)"}

```
 (async function () {
        const res = await fetch('https://tokenservice/api/DLToken', { method: 'POST' });        
        const {token}  = await res.json();
        console.log({token});
        window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
            {
                bot: bot,
                directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({token}),
                user: user,
                speechOptions: speechOptions,
                resize: 'detect',
                styleOptions: styleOptions
            },
            document.getElementById('BotChatGoesHere')
        );
```

I am getting this error in Edge and IE, in Chrome it works fine. Please suggest solution, will be obliged.

Comment: You need to use es5 bundle in IE. IE 11 doesn't support `async/await` keyword. Please try to use `https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat-es5.js`. You could refer to [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1326) to see how to make it compatible in IE 11. Besides, I checked the [official demo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/01.b.getting-started-es5-bundle) of es5 bundle and it can work well in both IE and Edge, you could also refer to it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, its working now :)

Comment: Great. Then I'll put the answer below.

Comment: Sure, Thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE 11 doesn't support `async/await` keyword. We need to use es5 bundle in IE. Please try to use `https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat-es5.js` instead.

Reference:

[Latest WebChat : IE11 Compatibility](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1326)

[Sample - Getting Started with Web Chat CDN with ES5 Polyfills](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/01.b.getting-started-es5-bundle)